# Send Data to Wearable from Phone via WearableListenerService

Tags: android, service, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I have a watch face which I am looking to send a few strings using the Data Layer. I have followed the [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events.html#Listen) by adding the service to the manifest and creating the `DataLayerListenerService` class.

What am I supposed to do to send data to the wearable from the service? I've done this before using `PutDataRequest` in my config activity which works. I now want to periodically send battery stats, weather info etc. to the wearable. How do I do this?

Here is my Class so far:

```
public class DataLayerListenerService extends WearableListenerService {

private static final String TAG = DataLayerListenerService.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String EXTRAS_PATH = "/extras";
private static final String START_ACTIVITY_PATH = "/start-activity";
private static final String DATA_ITEM_RECEIVED_PATH = "/data-item-received";
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

public static void LOGD(final String tag, String message) {
    if (Log.isLoggable(tag, Log.DEBUG)) {
        Log.d(tag, message);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
    LOGD(TAG, "onDataChanged: " + dataEvents);
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        ConnectionResult connectionResult = mGoogleApiClient
                .blockingConnect(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (!connectionResult.isSuccess()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "DataLayerListenerService failed to connect to GoogleApiClient, "
                    + "error code: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
            return;
        }
    }

    // Loop through the events and send a message back to the node that created the data item.
    for (DataEvent event : dataEvents) {
        Uri uri = event.getDataItem().getUri();
        String path = uri.getPath();
        if (EXTRAS_PATH.equals(path)) {
            // Get the node id of the node that created the data item from the host portion of
            // the uri.
            String nodeId = uri.getHost();
            // Set the data of the message to be the bytes of the Uri.
            byte[] payload = uri.toString().getBytes();

            // Send the rpc
            Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, nodeId, DATA_ITEM_RECEIVED_PATH,
                    payload);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, create an instance of [GoogleApiClient](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client), when you want to make a connection to one of the Google APIs provided in the Google Play services library. You need to create an instance of GoogleApiClient ("Google API Client"). The Google API Client provides a common entry point to all the Google Play services and manages the network connection between the user's device and each Google service.

Define a [`WearableListenerService`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService) which receives the [message](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html). It receives events from other nodes, such as data changes, messages or connectivity events.

Send a message thru [`MessageApi`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageApi), messages are delivered to connected network nodes. Multiple wearable devices can be connected to a user’s handheld device. Each connected device in the network is considered a node. With multiple connected devices, you must consider which nodes receive the messages.

Then implement [`MessageApi.MessageListener`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageApi.MessageListener) used with `addListener(GoogleApiClient, MessageApi.MessageListener)` to receive message events. Callers wishing to be notified of events in the background should use `WearableListenerService`. Then, receive the message and use a LocalBroadcastManager to elaborate the message and display the value on the wear.

Here's a related SO ticket: [Send message from wearable to phone and then immediately reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911579/send-message-from-wearable-to-phone-and-then-immediately-reply)